# Type system not allowing subtype as a type constructor

Tags: scala, generics, types

I'm trying to build the following type structure for a library I'm writing, and I'm having trouble with the type system.

**CarLike**

```scala
trait CarLike[T, C <: CarLike[T,C]] {
  val parts: Seq[T]
  def crash(other: C, speed: Int): C
  //... other methods
}
```

**SimpleCar**

```scala
class SimpleCar[T](val parts: Seq[T]) extends CarLike[T, SimpleCar[T]] {
  def crash(other: SimpleCar[T], speed: Int) = {
    //Some logic to crash with the other car
    val newParts = damage(parts) //parts have changed
    new SimpleCar(newParts)
  }
  //...other methods
}
```

**SportsCar**

```scala
class SportsCar(val sParts: Seq[String]) extends SimpleCar[String](sParts){
  override def crash(other: SimpleCar[String], speed: Int): SimpleCar[String] = {
    //Some other logic for crashing a sport car
    val newParts = damage(parts) //parts have changed
    new SportsCar(newParts)
  }
  //...other methods
}
```

**Crasher**

```scala
case class Crasher[T, C <: CarLike[T,C]](
                          partsDamager: T => T,
                          carChecker: C => Seq[T]
                          /*... more parameters*/
                          ){
  def test(cycles:Int) = {
    //Some logic to run a crash of two cars
  }
}
```

**Code**

```scala
//...
val crasher = Crasher[String, SportsCar](
  (s: String) => s.tail,
  (c: SportsCar) => c.parts.filter(p => p.length > 0)
  /*Many arguments*/
)
crasher.test(20)
//...
```

The idea is to allow the user of the library to be able to choose between using the default `SimpleCar` and implementing his own implementation of `CarLike`.
Also, users can choose the type for the car's parts. In this simple example the parts are `String`, but can easily be a custom class, which can be leveraged in the `crash` method of a custom class.

When compiling, I get the following compilation error:

```
type arguments [String,my.package.SportsCar] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T,C <: crashing.CarLike[T,C]]
    val crasher = Crasher[String, SportsCar](
```

Clearly there's something I'm missing here. Why doesn't the compiler agree that `SportsCar` is a legal subtype of `CarLike`?

Comment: You might have oversimplified the code for posting here on SO. Ignoring the **Crasher** and **Code** sections, I'm unable to get `SportsCar` to compile for reasons that might, or might not, be related to the error you're seeing.

Comment: @jwvh, thanks. I actually compiled my example code and it fails with the error shown in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SportsCar is not a `CarLike[String, SportsCar]`, it is a `CarLike[String, SimpleCar[String]]`. Note that `SportsCar extends SimpleCar[String]`, but that doesn't help, as `CarLike` is not covariant in `C`.

You can't really make `CarLike` covariant in `C`, as its `crash` method accepts a `C`. Instead, you can pass `SimpleCar[String]` to `Crasher` (after all, sports cars can crash with other cars, right?):

```
val crasher = Crasher[String, SimpleCar[String]](
  s => s.tail,
  c => c.parts.filter(p => p.length > 0)
)
```

Or, you can modify `Crasher` to take another type parameter:

```
case class Crasher[T, C <: CarLike[T, C], X <: C](partsDamager: T => T,
                                                  carChecker: X => Seq[T]) {
  // ...
}

val crasher = Crasher[String, SimpleCar[String], SportsCar](
  s => s.tail,
  c => c.parts.filter(p => p.length > 0)
)
```